# How is /ɑ:/ realized in British English: [ɑː] or more relaxed than [ɑː]?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, phonology, phonetics, vowels

I know that /ɑː/ is [*open back unrounded vowel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_unrounded_vowel) and is found a lot in British English. It is the vowel in *bath, father, bar, car* etc in British English. In American English, this vowel is found in *bar, father, car* (but not *bath*!).

But when I listen to the audio given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_unrounded_vowel), [IPA chart website](https://www.ipachart.com/) and [this IPA chart website](https://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/), I feel that pronouncing the vowel exactly like /ɑː/ would sound stilted.

I listened to many British people when pronouncing this vowel and they do not sound like this at all to me (non-native). If I heard them correctly, they were pronouncing /ɑː/ as not [ɑː] but something more relaxed or at least not that back and long as the audios in the above websites suggest.

**Bath:** [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bath), [Lexico powered by Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bath): the word "bath" is pronounced not with [ɑː] but something more relaxed than [ɑː]. I tried to pronounce it with [ɑː] but it sounds unnatural.

**Question:** Do British people usually pronounce /ɑː/ as [ɑː] or relaxed and shorter than [ɑː]? Am I hearing them correctly?

Comment: There is a criterion of relative  length for [ɑ:], as for all long vowels: it shortened before fortis consonants [t,k,p, …] and has its normal length before the others (lenis consonants).

Comment: I don't believe that IPA has a set length for [ɑ:]. All that this notation really means is that /ɑ:/ is pronounced longer than a short vowel like /ʌ/. And this is certainly true in British English — for some speakers, the principal difference between /ʌ/ and /ɑ:/ is the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker of British English (Surrey), I pronounce all those words with a fronted vowel [**ɑ̟**]. It's also a bit raised. In fact, all the people around me pronounce them with [**ɑ̟**]. [ɑː] is considered too "posh" in my neck of woods.

Comment: What is meant by "raised"?

Comment: @Sphinx - it means the tongue is positioned a bit higher in the mouth (more towards high vowels).